# Need a grouping Solution for a Collection

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Need a grouping in XSL for a desired output in XML

Source XML is :

```
<DATA_DS>
    <G_REQUEST_ID>3060814</G_REQUEST_ID>
    <LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>
            <PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>1</PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000223</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error1</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>
            <PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>2</PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000223</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error2</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>
            <PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>3</PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000225</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error5</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>
            <PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>4</PROJECT_ERROR_LINE>
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000225</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error6</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
    </LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
</DATA_DS>
```

Required Output XML is:

```
<DATA_DS>
    <G_REQUEST_ID>3060814</G_REQUEST_ID>
    <LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>         
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000223</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error1</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error2</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>     
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000225</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error5</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error6</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
    </LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
</DATA_DS>
```

Please provide xsl 2.0 using for each loop. Need to use this transformation in Oracle ICS.

My Apologies for adding question in comments.
Need to concatenate values of the repeating elements in group. Need to keep single element for the repeating. Need guidance.

Required output is

```
<DATA_DS>
    <G_REQUEST_ID>3060814</G_REQUEST_ID>
    <LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>         
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000223</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error1+Error2</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
        <PROJECT_ERROR>     
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000225</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error5+Error6</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
        </PROJECT_ERROR>
    </LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
</DATA_DS>
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Application is not allowing me to post only the code. So I added text. Need to transform source xml to target xml . Need a solution.

Comment: "Need a solution" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **XSLT 2.0**, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DATA_DS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="G_REQUEST_ID"/>
        <LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="LIST_PROJECT_ERROR/PROJECT_ERROR" group-by="ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/PROJECT_ERR_MSG"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </LIST_PROJECT_ERROR>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To get the result shown in the addition to your question, change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/PROJECT_ERR_MSG"/>
```

to:

```
<PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/PROJECT_ERR_MSG" separator="+"/>
</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Works Perfect. Can you please validate the below code as I built by referring many blogs.

Comment: AFAICT it's the same thing just (unnecessarily) longer.

Comment: Mick, can you please help me in concatenating the repeat element values of the same group. i.e.
 <PROJECT_ERROR>         
            <ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>SB100000223</ERROR_PROJECT_NUMBER>
            <PROJECT_ERR_MSG>Error1 + Error2</PROJECT_ERR_MSG>          
        </PROJECT_ERROR>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: I apologies. Edited the question.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Great help, perfect. Thanks.